# MySQL active after every boot, but I only want it to start when I need it

Tags: 20.04, mysql

Whenever I boot, when I type `systemctl status mysql.service`, I see MySQL is running. I want to manually activate MySQL whenever I need it. I forget to turn off every single time I don't need the service. How can I get the setup I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop MySQL from starting when the computer starts you disable it in two steps:

1. First stop MySQL from running:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop mysql.service
   ```
2. Then see to it that it won't start when restarting the computer:

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable mysql.service
   ```

Comment: It gives update-rc.d: error: Permission denied. Would it pose a problem sir?

Comment: Didn't work. Mysql is still active after reboot.

Comment: @hakan-demir: Correct, I edited my post and clarified some

Answer (score 1):

`systemctl disable mysql.service` to disable service on boot.

Type `systemctl start mysql.service` when you need and `systemctl stop mysql.service` to stop.

Comment: It gives `update-rc.d: error: Permission denied`. Would it pose a problem sir?

Comment: Didn't work. Mysql is still active after reboot.